# Element Directive Not Working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, element, directive

I am using Yeoman so I don't know if it's causing this element directive to not work. So this html template is not showing. I tried using include to see if something was wrong with my code and include worked...so something is going wrong with my directive. Please HELP!

This is my index where I call the directive element:

```
<div class="announcements">
  <div class="announcement-block">
    <announcement-block-update></announcement-block-update>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is my javascript:

```
(function() {
  var app = angular.module('announcementApp', [
    'ngAnimate',
    'ngAria',
    'ngCookies',
    'ngMessages',
    'ngResource',
    'ngRoute',
    'ngSanitize',
    'ngTouch'
  ]);

  app.directive('announcementBlockUpdate',function(){

    var announcementsObject = {
      type: 'UPDATE',
      announcement: 'DISA Maps are almost complete! Look foward to reporting out at the project share next week.'
    };


    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      templateUrl: '../views/update-announcement.html',
      controller: function(){
        this.announcement = announcementsObject;
      },
      controllerAs: 'announcement'
    };

  });


})();
```

This is my HTML template:

```
<div class="event-highlight update"></div>
    <div class="wrap">
    <div class="announcement-description">{{announcement.type}}</div>
    <div class="announcement">{{announcement.announcement}}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: hmm... should that be announcement.announcement.announcement since you are using controllerAs?

Answer (score 0):

Your template has an extra closing `</div>` tag. Not sure if that's related to the problem you're having or not.

Otherwise, your code looks fine. You're initializing the app somewhere in your html, right?

```
<div class="announcements" ng-app="announcementApp">
```

Answer (score 0):

## TL;DR

Way below is a working code snippet based on what you posted.

## Explanation

Instead of trying to specify the controllerAs property, set up two-way databinding between the main controller and the directive scope. This will allow you to simply update the controller (either from a service or resource) and the directive will also update automatically. This is thanks to isolate scopes, which you can learn more about [here](https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-understanding-isolate-scope).

## Code

```js
(function() {
  var app = angular.module('announcementApp', []);

  app.directive('announcementBlockUpdate', function() {


    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      template: '<div class="event-highlight update"></div><div class="wrap"><div class="announcement-description">{{announcement.type}}</div><div class="announcement">{{announcement.announcement}}</div></div>',
      scope: {
        announcement: '='
      }
    };

  });

  app.controller('announcementCtrl', function($scope) {
    var announcementsObject = {
      type: 'UPDATE',
      announcement: 'DISA Maps are almost complete! Look foward to reporting out at the project share next week.'
    };

    // Change the announcement here...
    $scope.announcement = announcementsObject;
  });

})();
```

```css
.announcements {
  min-height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 10px;
}
.announcement-block {
  min-height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>


<div ng-app="announcementApp">
  <div ng-controller="announcementCtrl">
    <div class="announcements">
      <div class="announcement-block">
        <announcement-block-update announcement="announcement"></announcement-block-update>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No luck. I copied the code exactly and still does not work for me. Would you suggest doing it this way if I will use the same template for all my announcements? I will have more than one announcement (same style just different 'type'

Also...why did my first attempt not work? I did it just like the tutorials

Comment: I did that just so the code snippet would work. Does the snippet work when you click "Run code snippet"? It works for me, so double check that you copied everything over correctly. Be sure to specify the `ng-app` and `ng-controller` attributes correctly.

Comment: The reason your first attempt did not work was that the `announcementObject` was bound to the controller instance instead of the scope. With directives you shouldn't typically bind to the controller instance. The more configurable approach is to set up the isolated binding  with the parent controller scope. That way your parent controller can call a service to get the announcements, and add them to the scope. Once they are added to the scope, the directive will update as well, since we specified the two-way binding when we set `<announcement-block-update announcement="announcement"></ann..`.

Answer (score 0):

Error in your html, the following:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="announcement-description">{{announcement.type}}</div>
    <div class="announcement">{{announcement.announcement}}</div>
</div>
```

should be inside of

```
<div class="event-highlight update"></div>
```